the string "sendGalRefreshToken error: Internal error encountered. 500" was thrown, throw an Error :)
while running the test suite from Google Smart home, I encountered this issue:
Google Account Linking Test Refresh Token 3 s. Failed
the string "sendGalRefreshToken error: Internal error encountered. 500" was thrown, throw an Error :)
This is happening while testing Account linking on my server.
I don't receive any communication from Google upon getting these error.
is any body seeing the same issue?
Run the Test Suite
Getting the result below:
Google Account Linking Test Refresh Token 3 s. Failed
the string "sendGalRefreshToken error: Internal error encountered. 500" was thrown, throw an Error :)
Expecting to get a pass result.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
